# Revit API InvalidOperationException: Invalid number of references. Ironpython

Tags: ironpython, revit-api

In this code, I am trying to create a new dimension by boundary lines as a reference, but it throws me  InvalidOperationException: Invalid number of references. I want to add a new dimension to each line of the boundary.

Can anyone help me?

```
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import FilteredElementCollector, BuiltInCategory, Transaction, Plane
from Autodesk.Revit.UI import Selection

doc=__revit__.ActiveUIDocument.Document
uidoc=__revit__.ActiveUIDocument

filledregion_ids=uidoc.Selection.GetElementIds()
filledregion_elements=[]
for id in filledregion_ids:
    filledregion_elements.append(doc.GetElement(id))

curve_ref_even=ReferenceArray()
curve_ref_odd=ReferenceArray()
count=0
boundcount=0
regcount=0

newplane=Plane.CreateByThreePoints(XYZ(100,0,0),XYZ(0,100,0),XYZ(0,0,0))
'''Getting filled regions'''
for region in filledregion_elements:
    boundary=region.GetBoundaries()
    for bound in boundary:
        boundcount+=1
        print(boundcount)  
        lastline=list(bound)[0]
        for lines in bound:
            if (count//2)==0:
             curve_ref_even.Append(lines.Reference)
             print(curve_ref_even)
             if len(list(curve_ref_even))==2:
              t= Transaction(doc, "Create dimension")
              t.Start()
              doc.Create.NewDimension(doc.ActiveView,lines,curve_ref_even)
              t.Commit()
             count+=1
            else:
             curve_ref_odd.Append(lines.Reference)
             print(curve_ref_odd)
             if len(list(curve_ref_odd))==2:
              t= Transaction(doc, "Create dimension")
              t.Start()
              doc.Create.NewDimension(doc.ActiveView,lines,curve_ref_odd)
              t.Commit()
              count+=1

    boundcount=0
    count=0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest separating your code into two separate parts, at least. One part to handle the logic that picks the reference points from the list of boundaries and ensures that you have got the right pairs together, and a second part that actually creates the dimensions. What you are doing above looks too clever for my taste, and not trustworthy. I am not sure you can assume any specific order in the list of the boundary segments returned by `GetBoundaries`. By the way, The Building Coder provides a whole list of articles on [creating dimensioning](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.45).